# githubData.map is not a function when trying to render data from API

Tags: reactjs, github-api

I'm trying to work with GithubAPI and i can get the all the data i want with Axios and `componentDidMount`, but for some reason, when i try to render with map, i get this annoying error and i dont know why.

This is my code:

```
class SearchResult extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      githubData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`${api.baseUrl}/users/${this.props.location.state.userName}`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('res', res);
        this.setState({ githubData: res.data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { githubData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="search-result">
        {githubData.map((name, index) => (
          <p>{name.name}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResult;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub user endpoint returning an object, so `githubData` is an object not an array.
in your script, you treated as an array.
`{}.map` will return an error

Comment: it should be 
```this.state = {
  githubData: {}
};
```

render:
```<div className="search-result">
  { githubData.name }
</div>
```